# Assigning a variable to the output of a findstr/find combination

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, find, findstr

I have a log file, that prefixes all lines in it with the date and time. For instance:

```
2015-02-04 16:11 Error Message: Important Bit Useless Information.
```

I wish to write a batchfile that when run picks out all the lines from the last hour and then counts how many of these lines contain "Important Bit" and then output this count if it's greater than a given value.

The part I am having difficulty with is basically the main part. I have set up the batchfile, it finds the date, finds the last ten minute period. I cannot then get the file to do the above.

My current command for this is as below, where date and now are assigned to the current date and time:

```
set count="findstr /G:“%date% %now%” “C:\Documents\File.txt” | find /C "Important Bit""

If %count% geq 5 echo Found %count% lines >> C:\Documents\Output.txt
```

When I run this, as far as I can tell, nothing happens. I've tried using a FOR command as well, but this still wouldn't work.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like the following:

```
set /a COUNT=0
for /f %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"Important Bit" test.txt') do (
  set /a COUNT=COUNT + 1
)
echo %COUNT%
```